# createReducer builder notation callback error

Tags: typescript, redux

I'm trying to use `createReducer` with the builder syntax and create a reducer that updates the `auth` state based on whether the user successfully logs in. However, i'm getting a TS2769 error. This is being caused by the second `builder.addCase` where I'm trying to adjust the state when a user fails to log in. Could someone review my code and help me understand what's causing the error?

My code:

```
export interface AuthInterface {
    loading: boolean;
    userToken: boolean | null;
    error: string | null;
    success: boolean;
}

export interface AuthState {
    auth: AuthInterface;
}

const initialState: AuthState = {
    auth: {
        loading: false,
        userToken: null,
        error: null,
        success: false,
    }
}

export const login = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/login",
    async (loginData: LoginData, thunkAPI: any) => {
        try {
            const { email, password } = loginData;
            const res = await axios.post<UserLogin>(
                "http://localhost:4000/login",
                {
                    email: email,
                    password: password,
                }
            );
            return res.data;
        }
        catch (error) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
        }
    }
)

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action: PayloadAction<AuthInterface>) => {
            state.auth.loading = false;
            state.auth.success = true;
            state.auth.error = null;
        })
        //this is entire block is underlined red
        builder.addCase(login.rejected, (state, action:PayloadAction<AuthInterface>) => {
            state.auth.loading = false;
            state.auth.success = false;
            state.auth.error = action.payload.error
        })
    }
});
```

My error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(actionCreator: AsyncThunkRejectedActionCreator<LoginData, AsyncThunkConfig>, reducer: CaseReducer<AuthState, PayloadAction<...>>): ActionReducerMapBuilder<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: WritableDraft<AuthState>, action: { payload: AuthInterface; type: string; }) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CaseReducer<AuthState, PayloadAction<unknown, string, { arg: LoginData; requestId: string; requestStatus: "rejected"; aborted: boolean; condition: boolean; } & ({ rejectedWithValue: true; } | ({ ...; } & {})), SerializedError>>'.
      Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
        Type 'PayloadAction<unknown, string, { arg: LoginData; requestId: string; requestStatus: "rejected"; aborted: boolean; condition: boolean; } & ({ rejectedWithValue: true; } | ({ rejectedWithValue: false; } & {})), SerializedError>' is not assignable to type '{ payload: AuthInterface; type: string; }'.
          Types of property 'payload' are incompatible.
            Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'AuthInterface'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, reducer: CaseReducer<AuthState, { payload: AuthInterface; type: string; }>): ActionReducerMapBuilder<AuthState>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'AsyncThunkRejectedActionCreator<LoginData, AsyncThunkConfig>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

If I replace `action: PayloadAction<AuthInterface>` with `action: any` it works? But then I would get trouble with `action.payload.error`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around with the following code:

```
export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
        .addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action: PayloadAction<AuthInterface>) => {
            console.log(action);
            state.auth.loading = false;
            state.auth.success = true;
            state.auth.error = action.payload.error;
        })
        .addCase(login.rejected, (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
            console.log(action);
            state.auth.success = false;
            state.auth.error = action.payload
        })
        
    }
});
```

I'm still not sure why I'm not allow to put `action: PayloadAction<AuthInterface>`